# does Afterglow Player(simple video platform from video.js) work with advertising, especially Vast?

Tags: video.js, vast

everybody.

I have just built my own video player from Afterglow player.
Afterglow player is a super simple video player implementation based on video.js, taking out the hassle of setting everything up.

Now, I am going to use Vast(Video Ad Serving Template) for advertising on my own player.
But on the Afterglow player, Events don't work yet.
(video.js provides some cool events to which you can bind stuff. As afterglow has self contained initiation process, it's not that easy to make all provided events work properly.)

In my opinion, we should use "videojs-contrib-ads" plugin(for the VAST) and it provides six interaction points (four events and two methods) which we can use in integration.

**So what I want to know is if Afterglow player could work with "videojs-contrib-ads"**

**Can I use VAST without this plugin on my customized afterglow player?**

If someone has got experiences with afterglow player advertisement, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In it's current state, afterglow does not support advertising. Maybe this can be added in the future, but for now, it's not on the list.

What you can of course do is to integrate the videojs-contrib-ads plugin into your custom build. You'd need to make it load in the initiation process and it should probably be working.

Also, afterglow *does* support video.js' events - they just aren't documented yet. Just call `afterglow.getPlayer('myPlayerID');` to get a raw video.js instance of your player. You could f.i. react to the `ended` event, like shown here: https://codepen.io/moay/pen/xVQMWM/?editors=1000